# Can we manage CameraX videoCapture speed?

Tags: android, video, android-camerax

I want to know, if we can manage Googles new CameraX api's vide capturing speed, for example record video in 2x speed or in slow mode. Any sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you can't record a video in 2x speed or any other speed different than 1x using CameraX.
Alternatively you can use **FFmpeg** to create a slow/fast motion video from an input video.

There are few ways to create a slow/fast motion video using ffmpeg, [see guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) - this process can be done in a few ways, the first one mentioned in the linked page is lossless and requires no re encoding so it is very fast.

If you don't know much about ffmpeg there are plenty of articles online and guides.
for using it in android I personally prefer [this library](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg), but there are plenty more option out there.